# Reading file from a folder in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to read `Test.xlsx` but the file is in another folder named `1`. Is there a way to specify the file location `file_loc`? I tried this but there seems to be an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


file_loc = "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept12_2022\1\Test.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")
A=df["N"].to_numpy()
print([A])
```

The error is

```
line 11
    file_loc = "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept12_2022\1\Test.xlsx"
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: one possible reason - your excel data is having some unsupported characters

Comment: The error is in specifying the file location, not the contents of the file as shown above.

Comment: You need to escape the \  characters in the path;
`file_loc = "C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\1\\Test.xlsx"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your path string to a raw string
`r'C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept12_2022\1\Test.xlsx'`

because `\1` converts to an emoji(`☺`).

Or replace single slash`\` with double slash`\\`
`"C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\1\\Test.xlsx"`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


file_loc = r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept12_2022\1\Test.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")
A=df["N"].to_numpy()
print([A])
```